# How do I create a recent feed view, using a collection group filtered firebase firestore query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of user subscriptions to books that contain the userId and the bookId. I have a collection of Books, which each have a collection of chapters. Those chapters have timestamp fields. I need a list of all of the chapters that a user is subscribed to, in reverse chronological order, and I am really only going to be needing the most recent 10 most of the time, since it will be shown on a scrolling listview in Flutter.

Can this even be done on Firebase? I know that I can do a collectionGroup and order that, for the chapters, and I can filter that by up to ten values if I include the bookId in the chapter document. But is it really a 10 subscription limit for my users? More than that would need some sort of bizarre parallel queries, or something.

Here's what the database looks like:
[image: the user_profiles collection]
[image: the books collection]

Comment: could you share the screenshot of the Firestore database from the Firebase console.

Comment: Of course! I simply need to know what sort of query would efficiently get the most recently authored chapters the the user is subscribed to.

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you share the code which you have tried?